# Foreign Key Constraint SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Keep getting the error cannot add foreign key constraint, any ideas probably a noob mistake but i am new to SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE tblDept (

  Dept VARCHAR(50),
  Name VARCHAR(50)
  );

CREATE TABLE tblPersonnel (

  PersID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FullName VARCHAR(100),
  Address VARCHAR(100),
  Dept VARCHAR(50),
  Grade VARCHAR (2),
  Salary INT,
  DateOfBirth DATE,
  Manager INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(Dept) REFERENCES tblDept(Dept)

  );

 CREATE TABLE PersonnelPhone (

   PersID INT, 
   Extension INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (PersID) REFERENCES tblPersonnel(PersID)
   );

 CREATE TABLE tblPhone (
   Extension INT,
   DeviceType VARCHAR,
   VoiceMail BOOLEAN,
   FOREIGN KEY (Extension) REFERENCES tblPersonnelPhone(Extension)
   );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Extension` in second table must be `PRIMARY KEY`.

You probably want to implement many-to-many relationship. In this case, `Extension` in `PersonnelPhone` should be `FOREIGN KEY` and `Extension` in `tblPhone` should be `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Ditto, `Dept` in first table, used by foreign key defined in second table.

Comment: Thank you very much for for your help! makes sense now, i lost hours to this haha

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in there. Here's a working schema definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tblDept (
  Dept VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
  Name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tblPersonnel (
  PersID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  FullName VARCHAR(100), 
  Address VARCHAR(100), 
  Dept VARCHAR(50), 
  Grade VARCHAR(2), 
  Salary INT, 
  DateOfBirth DATE, 
  Manager INT, 
  FOREIGN KEY(Dept) REFERENCES tblDept(Dept)
);

CREATE TABLE tblPersonnelPhone (
  PersID INT, 
  Extension INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  FOREIGN KEY (PersID) REFERENCES tblPersonnel(PersID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblPhone (
  Extension INT, 
  DeviceType VARCHAR(100), 
  VoiceMail BOOLEAN, 
  FOREIGN KEY (Extension) REFERENCES tblPersonnelPhone(Extension)
);
```

For future reference, use SQLFiddle for sharing these types of problems: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ce29

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time its highly appreciated, Also thanks i will bookmark that site.